# How to scrape the specific text from kworb and extract it as an excel file?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the positions, the artists and the songs from a ranking list on kworb. For example: https://kworb.net/spotify/country/us_weekly.html

I used the following script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://kworb.net/spotify/country/us_weekly.html")
content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.get_text())
```

And here is the output:

```
ITUNES
WORLDWIDE
ARTISTS
CHARTS
DON'T PRAY
RADIO
SPOTIFY
YOUTUBE
TRENDING
HOME


CountriesArtistsListenersCities




Spotify Weekly Chart - United States - 2023/02/09 | Totals


PosP+Artist and TitleWksPk(x?)StreamsStreams+Total

1
+1
SZA - Kill Bill
9
1(x5)
15,560,813
+247,052
148,792,089
2
-1
Miley Cyrus - Flowers
4
1(x3)
13,934,413
-4,506,662
75,009,251
3
+20
Morgan Wallen - Last Night
2
3(x1)
11,560,741
+6,984,649
16,136,833
...
```

How do I only get the positions, the artists and the songs separately and store it as an excel first?

expected output:

```
Pos         Artist            Songs
1           SZA               Kill Bill
2           Miley Cyrus       Flowers
3           Morgan Wallen     Last Night
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice to scrape tables is using [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) it uses `BeautifulSoup` under the hood for you.

```
import pandas as pd

#find table by id and select first index from list of dfs
df = pd.read_html('https://kworb.net/spotify/country/us_weekly.html', attrs={'id':'spotifyweekly'})[0]

#split the column by delimiter and creat your expected columns
df[['Artist','Song']]=df['Artist and Title'].str.split(' - ', n=1, expand=True)

#pick your columns and export to excel
df[['Pos','Artist','Song']].to_excel('yourfile.xlsx', index = False)
```

Alternative based on direct approach:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://kworb.net/spotify/country/hk_weekly.html").content, 'html.parser')

data = []

for e in soup.select('#spotifyweekly tr:has(td)'):
    data .append({
        'Pos':e.td.text,
        'Artist':e.a.text,
        'Song':e.a.find_next_sibling('a').text
    })
pd.DataFrame(data).to_excel('yourfile.xlsx', index = False)
```

##### Outputs

| Pos | Artist | Song |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SZA | Kill Bill |
| 2 | Miley Cyrus | Flowers |
| 3 | Morgan Wallen | Last Night |
| 4 | Metro Boomin | Creepin' |
| 5 | Lil Uzi Vert | Just Wanna Rock |
| 6 | Drake | Rich Flex |
| 7 | Metro Boomin | Superhero (Heroes & Villains) [with Future & Chris Brown] |
| 8 | Sam Smith | Unholy |

...

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, how to set the range limit for the ranking? For example, Pos 1-100

Comment: Also, another question. If I want to scape the list for another countries like Hong Kong: https://kworb.net/spotify/country/hk_weekly.html. It comes out an error: line 25, in <module>
    'Song':c[4]
IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: This is not focus of your OP and would be predestined to be asked as new question next time - However, use `pandas` as recommended to scrape tables and you avoid the index issue but take a look in edit, in addition you could slice your `dataframe` `df[['Pos','Artist','Song']][:100].to_excel('yourfile.xlsx', index = False)` to get the top 100.